# ActionBar.OnNavigationListener fires no matter which item was clicked in ACtionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a problem.
I have an action bar. It has a drop down list and it has an overflow button and another button some where in between.

Because I use a drop down, I am setting the action bar to use this mode:

```
 mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mActionBarNavigationAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

My mOnNavifationListener is set to call a REST api depending on which item I chose in the drop down list.
This works as excepted.

The problem is, if I click on the overflow button to reveal extra options (such as settings or more importantly, Signout), I still get the navigation listener activated.
So I thought. Ok let's try to distinguish between the buttons using their position or id which are passed as parameters in onNavigationItemSelected method.
So I added an if statement that checks the position parameter. But...
It seems that the position of the overflow button is ALSO 0 (exactly like the position of the first item in the drop down list, so it passes the check and calls the REST api which is not good.
Also, the third button (not the drop down list or the overflow), has a position of 1 which effectively calls the other REST api...

I can't find a way to distinguish between the items in the action bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd strongly consider replacing your use of list navigation, as that is officially deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next shipping version of Android.

> I still get the navigation listener activated

I am not clear on what you mean by this. I also don't know which action bar you are referring to:

- native API Level 11+?
- `appcompat_v7`?
- ActionBarSherlock?

Ideally, `onNavigationItemSelected()` will be called when your activity first appears, then if the user chooses something from the `Spinner`. If you are saying that it is being called at other points in time, while unfortunate, this can be worked around by simply keeping track, in your own data member, of where you are in the `Spinner`, and only doing work if the `Spinner` position actually has changed. So, for example, if you start off showing position 0, and the user taps something which causes `onNavigationItemSelected()` to be called again with position 0, you know that nothing needs changing, because you are still on position 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I am using appcompat_v7. By "I still get the navigation listener activated" I mean that no matter which item I click in the ActionBar, being it the drop down list or the overflow button or any other button that is in there, the navigation listener gets called and therefor, the implementation inside is executed, leading eventually to a REST api call. I'm trying to find a way to distinguish between all the buttons. Currently they all return either 0 or 1 both in i and l (the parameters I get in onNavigationItemSelected(int i, long l).

Comment: But what you have suggested as a work around might be exactly what I need. I'll try to implement it. Thank you!
Btw I registered to your Advanced Action Bar Techniques webinar. Really looking forward to it now :)